# Http content causing errors with Https content

Tags: javascript, http, https

I have a page which is Https, I am pulling some rss feeds using the Google ATOM API. I am getting an error about insecure data. Is there a way to get the rss feeds without causing the error?

Comment: all content needs to be https. Use https instead of http with the feeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are reporting is due to mixing the security contexts.  The only way to avoid this message is to ensure that both sources are either secure `https://` or just `http://`.

Comment: thanks for the tip just realised i was pointing to a http based library which I just copied locally in the end.